# delete position (C++)

Tags: c++, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have a question. Reading this part of code:

```
int* res = NULL;
while((res = coda.Pop())!= NULL){
    std::cout << "Pop: " << *res << std::endl;
    delete res;
}
```

(where Pop() is a function in a class that returns a pointer to int)

I asked myself: what is the difference if I take off

```
delete res;
```

from the while cicle, as this:

```
int* res = NULL;
while((res = coda.Pop())!= NULL){
    std::cout << "Pop: " << *res << std::endl;  
}
delete res;
```

The program compile and run in both cases

Comment: You'll leak all the items in the list, presumably.

Comment: _"What happens if I don't delete things?"_ - Well, you know what `delete` does? If you don't do it, then that doesn't happen. Did you mean to ask what delete is for, or why it matters, or ... what?

Comment: Editorial tip: You can write your loop simply as `while (int* res = coda.Pop()) { /* ... */ }`

Comment: You should get used to std::unique_ptr and std::shared_ptr to avoid memory leaks due to transferring ownership.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `coda` seems to be a container and the method `Pop()` removes single allocated element from it. As this value was previously dynamically allocated (with `new`) it should be deallocated (with `delete`) to let OS memory manager know that this memory is free and can be reused.
In the first case you are deallocating all variables you pop from container.
The second example deallocates nothing (it will delete null pointer which is defined by standard but does nothing) and all pointers are lost. This is called a memory leak.

Though second example will work fine if you have 0 in `coda` but this is not the thing you would want to rely on.

Comment: No, even for 1 element there will be a memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

In the second case you're having a memory leak because you don't delete anything. The `delete` after the loop tries to delete a null pointer.

Answer (score 1):

My C++ is a big rusty, but the second part looks like a potential memory leak depending on what `coda.PopTesta()` is popping.
Given that it is returning an `int*` it's safe to say that whatever `coda.PopTesta()` is allocated using a `new`. This means that in the second case, if your `coda.popTesta()` pops more than one value, all except the last value will NOT be deleted and cause memory leak.

CORRECTION: The last value will leak too. As the while look will terminate one res becomes NULL, and delete on NULL does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You leak all of the values. None of your dynamically allocated memory is freed.

Answer (score 0):

`coda` seems to be of type `stack`. The stack seems to contain pointers to `int` that where previously allocated by `new`.

So, if the stack contains any number of elements where count is `> 0`, the elements will never be freed in the second case (the last one will not be freed, too). Because the loop runs as long as `res != NULL`.

In the first case, each element is taken from the stack by calling `coda.Pop()`, outputted and the memory is freed, by the `delete` statement.

If the pointers to `int` in the stack are just used as a reference (e.g weak-pointer, previously just assigned and not explicitly allocated by `new`) and the stack is not the owner of the pointers, there should not be a `delete` at all.